# how to dynamically serialize List

Tags: json, serialization, jackson

I am using Jackson library and problem is how to dynamically serialize LIST (arraylist) to JSON only if size of list is > 0. Anyone can advise what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate the getter method, that Jackson will use by default, to only serialize it the list is non empty (size > 0). E.g.

```
class ClassWithList {
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```